# How can implement Flurry Analytics for Samsung Tizen TV?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I googled for Flurry Analytics but I didn't find any SDK for Tizen TV.

Please tell me that Flurry Analytics SDK is available for Tizen TV?

If SDK is not available then please suggest me is there any way to implement it by custom?

Answer (score 0):

For Tizen, there is no available SDK like Flurry Analytics.
What do you want to do? Do you want to get the report for your apps? or, want to make SDKs for Tizen Apps?

Comment: I want to implement Flurry Analytics for Samsung Tizen TV apps. If there is no SDK for Tizen TV then could please suggest me custom implementation for Tizen TV?

Answer (score 0):

Tizen TV currently supports Web applications developed using javascript only. After research on [flurry documentation webpage](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/), I didn't find any information about javascript-only integration.

I think that in this situation the only solution is to use some other analytics framework which has 'pure js' support. [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) seem to be some possibility after quick research.

Comment: Is there any possibility to implement custom?

Comment: As I mentioned, TV devices have only web apps devlopment opened for public, which causes that any customization of non-JavaScript libraries is not possible. I suggest using some web-based framework instead.